# Code Signing Bundled exe

Tags: c#, exe, code-signing

We are signing our exe installer which will be released to the public, and this exe installer is a bundle of other exe installers.

The question is, in best practice, do we sign the bundled exe only, or we need to sign every nested exe inside the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't sign the "inner" exe, they could be altered after deployment and you would have no reliable way of checking that. It is best if you sign all your binaries.

Comment: Would an "Unknown publisher" dialog appear if the inner installers aren't signed?